# How to pinvoke a variable-length array of structs from GetTokenInformation() safely for 32-bit and 64-bit? C#

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm following the pinvoke code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146153/how-to-get-the-logon-sid-in-c/2146418#2146418) but am slightly scared by the marshalling of the variable-length array as size=1 and then stepping through it by calculating an offset instead of indexing into an array. Isn't there a better way? And if not, how should I do this to make it safe for 32-bit and 64-bit?

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public IntPtr Sid;
        public uint Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOKEN_GROUPS
    {
        public int GroupCount;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
        public SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Groups;
    };


public void SomeMethod()
{
    IntPtr tokenInformation;

    // ... 

    string retVal = string.Empty;
    TOKEN_GROUPS groups = (TOKEN_GROUPS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tokenInformation, typeof(TOKEN_GROUPS));
    int sidAndAttrSize = Marshal.SizeOf(new SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES());
    for (int i = 0; i < groups.GroupCount; i++)
    {
        // *** Scary line here: 
        SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES sidAndAttributes = (SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
              new IntPtr(tokenInformation.ToInt64() + i * sidAndAttrSize + IntPtr.Size), 
              typeof(SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES));

    // ... 
}
```

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338297/managed-to-unmanaged-code-call-causes-access-violation-sometimes) another approach of declaring the length of the array as much bigger than it's likely to be, but that seemed to have its own problems.

As a side question: When I step through the above code in the debugger I'm not able to evaluate `tokenInformation.ToInt64()` or `ToInt32()`. I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. But the line of code executes just fine!? What's going on here?

Comment: 51% ... where do you see that!? kidding - fair point I'd been really slack about that.

Comment: So any ideas whether ToInt64() is safe on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks okay -- as okay as any poking about in unmanaged land is, anyway.

However, I wonder why the start is `tokenInformation.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size` and not `tokenInformation.ToInt64() + 4` (as the GroupCount field type is an int and not IntPtr). Is this for packing/alignment of the structure or just something fishy? I do not know here.

Using `tokenInformation.ToInt64()` is important because on a 64-bit machine *will explode* (OverflowException) if the IntPtr value is larger than what an int can store. However, the CLR will handle a long just fine on both architectures and it doesn't change the actual value extracted from the IntPtr (and thus put back into the `new IntPtr(...)`).

Imagine this (untested) function as a convenience wrapper:

```
// unpacks an array of structures from unmanaged memory
// arr.Length is the number of items to unpack. don't overrun.
void PtrToStructureArray<T>(T[] arr, IntPtr start, int stride) {
   long ptr = start.ToInt64();
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++, ptr += stride) {
       arr[i] = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(ptr), typeof(T));
   }
}

var attributes = new SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[groups.GroupCount];
PtrToStructureArray(attributes, new IntPtr(tokenInformation.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size), sidAndAttrSize);
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean about IntPtr.Size. TOKEN_GROUPS.GroupCount should be uint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379624(v=vs.85).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx) and IntPtr.Size is 4 on 32-bit and 8 on 64-bit systems (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of guessing what the offset, is its generally better to use `Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(TOKEN_GROUPS), "Groups")` to get the correct offset to the start of the array.