# How to get Windows user name from SessionID?

Tags: c#, windows, sessionid

Is there a method in C# to retrieve the user name from a given session id?
(any session running on the system)

The Win API function [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does this, but I'm searching for this functionality in C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061143/how-to-get-a-unique-id-for-the-current-users-logon-session-in-windows-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ThirdBattleOfPanipat: This is more complicated than  WTSQuerySessionInformation is - and it's also Win API, not plain C#. So there's no method in the .NET framework?

Comment: There is no concept of "user name" associated with ASP.Net sessions... What exactly "user name" you want to get?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: This is used by a desktop allication, no ASP here.

Comment: .NET is focused on end-user and web applications, so as a general rule it excludes the more hard-core system management functions.  I'd be surprised if it contained a terminal services API.

Comment: Missed that it is desktop question. I don't believe you will find anything like this in .Net Framework... There is always [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=WTSQuerySessionInformation&namespace=[All])...

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Seems to be true. I googled a lot with no result.

Comment: How about using P/Invoke?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There seems to be no .NET integrated method for this.
So this is the current solution, using Windows Terminal services API:

```
    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WtsInfoClass wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out int pBytesReturned);
    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);

    public enum WtsInfoClass
    {
        WTSInitialProgram,
        WTSApplicationName,
        WTSWorkingDirectory,
        WTSOEMId,
        WTSSessionId,
        WTSUserName,
        WTSWinStationName,
        WTSDomainName,
        WTSConnectState,
        WTSClientBuildNumber,
        WTSClientName,
        WTSClientDirectory,
        WTSClientProductId,
        WTSClientHardwareId,
        WTSClientAddress,
        WTSClientDisplay,
        WTSClientProtocolType,
        WTSIdleTime,
        WTSLogonTime,
        WTSIncomingBytes,
        WTSOutgoingBytes,
        WTSIncomingFrames,
        WTSOutgoingFrames,
        WTSClientInfo,
        WTSSessionInfo,
    }

    public static string GetUsernameBySessionId(int sessionId, bool prependDomain) {
        IntPtr buffer;
        int strLen;
        string username = "SYSTEM";
        if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WTSUserName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1) {
            username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
            WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
            if (prependDomain) {
                if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WTSDomainName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1) {
                    username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer) + "\\" + username;
                    WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
        return username;
    }
```