# Custom action implemented with Installer class does not work when uninstalling

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I implemented installer to my WPF app by `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` class. I wanted to remove registryKey added by my app when uninstalling it, so I wrote follwing as a part of CustomAction.dll:

```cs
using System;

namespace CustomAction
{
    [System.ComponentModel.RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ActionSetting : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            var name = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            RemoveKey(name);

            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }

        private void RemoveKey(string Key)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regkey =
                    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                    @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
                regkey.DeleteValue(Key, false);
                regkey.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. In practice, anything I wrote, regardless of the contents it doesn't seems to be called.
I confirmed Uninstall method is definitely called, testing by some code like 
`MessageBox.Show("uninstalled")` .
What should I do? I feel like I should find other way not using `.dll`. I use Visual Studio 2017. thanks.

Comment: I noticed my code is little wrong because Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() returns project's name created for .dll (I mean, in this case it returns "CustomAction"). I fixed it, but problem was not solved. RegistryKey I wanted to delete still has remained...

Comment: I think Key is a reserved keyword, so I'd rename this for a start. Hard one to suggest anything, maybe add some error logging in the catch and run process monitor to see what is happening in the registry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Finally I found Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser got not "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" but "HKEY_USERS\.Default" when uninstalling, therefore the key registered on "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"  was not found. If I can know how to get "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" RegistryKey directory, I'd solve this issue, I guess.

Comment: Looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261491/write-registry-to-hkey-current-user-instead-of-hkey-users could be your problem then :)

Comment: Oh, that's gonna be useful. I'm really grateful for your help! Thank you.