# Can I rely on Remote Desktop Services service running on Windows 10 x64 (1803 or higher)?

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-services, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I'm working on a service (C#) that receives session-change notifications (specifically SessionLogon). The only piece of information I get with that notification is **`SessionId`**.

The ultimate goal is to check the logon user's profile (local/roaming AppData/MyCorp/MyApp folder) for a particular setting, and perform a task if it's there.

So I need to go from **SessionId** to something I can map to a user profile, like **LogonUserName** or **SID**. There are [solutions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061143/how-to-get-a-unique-id-for-the-current-users-logon-session-in-windows-c-sharp), but they involve the [**`WTSQuerySessionInformation`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw) API, which is documented to *fail if Remote Desktop Services isn't running*.

On past versions of Windows, some editions didn't include Remote Desktop functionality (usually the 'Home' editions, IIRC).

Does anyone know if I can ***rely*** on this service always being there in all editions of Windows 10 x64 (>=1803)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) says "no".

> Note
>
> You can use Remote Desktop to connect to Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise, Windows 8.1 and 8 Enterprise and Pro, Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate, and Windows Server versions newer than Windows Server 2008. **You can't connect to computers running a Home edition (like Windows 10 Home).**

(emphasis: me)